# ASP.NET DropDownList SelectedIndex resets after OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net

I have a DropDownList defined like this :

```
<td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="campagnes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="campagnes_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

And i am filling the DropDownList in the Page_Load inside !Page.IsPostBack check.

Each time i try to select one of the item, it will load the page and reset the selected index.

How can i save the selected index even after page loads ?

Comment: You have to show more code since this is not normal behaviour. Is `campagnes_SelectedIndexChanged` triggered?

Comment: it does save the selected index. your code somewhere else is causing it to reset. i suggest posting your code in full

Comment: They are right. Post your code. SelectedIndex always been saved

Comment: I notices that the "Value" of my items is the same for multiples of them and it is selecting the first item having this value in the list. Is it possible that it is the problem ?

Comment: I changed the Value of my items so they are all different and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this in your `Page_Load`

```
campagnes.DataSource = somelist;
campagnes.DataBind();
```

ensure you put that in a

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    campagnes.DataSource = somelist;
    campagnes.DataBind();
}
```

This will ensure that the dropdown only gets bound with data once.

What is happening is that when you fire of your method the `Page_Load` gets called first before the actual `SelectedItemChanged` events gets fired, and this causes the data to be bound again.

Comment: "And i am filling the DropDownList in the Page_Load inside !Page.IsPostBack check." - Original post.

Comment: This was just the obvious solution, but I am glad you got it working @GoranMottram